# Animation is crashing only in samsung galaxy note 8

Tags: android, android-animation, samsung-mobile, objectanimator

I am trying to achieve button flip animation on click of a button, I achieved it using **Object animator** and using **Animation set**. It is working in all the devices except Samsung galaxy note 8 and also in some realme device. When i try to run this in samsung it is causes **my entire app to hang for sometime**. I am not sure whether it is a code issue or device issue. I am pretty sure that there is no mistake on the code side, but just to be sure, posting the animation of code.

My Samsung galaxy note 8 is running on Android 9.

**top_to_bottom_anim.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="180"
        android:propertyName="rotationX"
        android:duration="@integer/anim_length" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="@integer/anim_length_half"
        android:duration="0" />
</set>
```

**bottom_to_top_anim.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="0" />


    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="-180"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:propertyName="rotationX"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:duration="@integer/anim_length" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="@integer/anim_length_half"
        android:duration="0" />
</set>
```

**layout_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:text="Add"
        android:textSize="14sp"
         />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnRemove"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:text="Remove"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val mSetTopDown: AnimatorSet by lazy {
        AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.top_to_bottom_anim) as AnimatorSet
    }

    private val mSetBottomUp: AnimatorSet by lazy {
        AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.bottom_to_top_anim) as AnimatorSet
    }

    private var isRemoveVisible = false


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_button)

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener {
            flipCard()

        }
        btnRemove.setOnClickListener {

        }
    }

    private fun flipCard() {
        if (!isRemoveVisible) {
            mSetTopDown.setTarget(btnAdd)
            mSetBottomUp.setTarget(btnRemove)
            mSetTopDown.start()
            mSetBottomUp.start()
            mSetTopDown.addListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
                override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {
                }

                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                    btnAdd.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }

                override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {
                }

                override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {
                }

            })
            isRemoveVisible = true
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something in animation?

Comment: show your crash information

Comment: There is no crash log as when I am trying to animate the app completely freezes and there is no logs, I have also check crash reports from my phone, but they also don't show anything.

Comment: you can search "fatal" or some error level logs from logcat, which can be useful for finding what happened

Comment: I have double check everything the entire app is freezing there is not log.

Comment: then you have to debug it with breakpoints and find out on which code it is freeezing

Comment: @RajatBeck have you found any solution?

Comment: No... removed the animation !!